# Mean of variable at the selection (SAS)

Tags: sql, statistics, sas, analytics

For expamle I have a table A with 2 variables, the first one is a customer id, and the second is the income of the customer which is in range from 100 to 200 US dollars. The task is to create a table B where I would have customers with mean of income 150 USD and the amount of customers should be maximal. In other words I need to have table B with the maximal amount of customers from table A and the mean of income among the customers of table B should be exactly equal to 150. Is there any elegant approach using SAS Enterprise Guide?

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant approach to getting such a maximal subset.  If there is, I am also very curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the records by income, low to high.  Then compute the mean of all records 1 - N.  Find N where mean = 150.

```
data test;
do id = 1 to 1000;
income = 100 + round(ranuni(1)*100,1);
output;
end;
run;

proc sort data=test;
by income;
run;

data want(where=(ave<=150));
set test;

retain sum 0;

sum = sum + income;
ave = sum / _n_;

drop sum;
run;
```

You want as many low values as possible.  This then lets you add large values to get the mean to 150.  So sorting by income should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A greedy algorithm might do the job well-enough, depending on the structure of the data.  This is definitely not guaranteed to be optimal, but it can be implemented relatively fast.

The idea is:

1. Calculate the average of all the records
2. If the average is $150 then stop
3. Remove the largest/smallest value to increase or decrease the average, as appropriate
4. If the average is $150 then stop
5. Repeat (1) until finished

This should work pretty well if the values cluster around $150.  If they are widely dispersed, then you might not get any records in the final bins.

If the algorithm works on your data, then there may be faster ways of implementing it.